# there is no package devtools in shiny server

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

in the code of `ui.R` and `server.R` I have installed and call `devtools` library using this:

```
library(devtools)
```

However when I put the file into `/srv/shiny-server/testapp`, in browser I receive this error:

> ERROR: there is no package called ‘devtools’

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I guess the problem is exactly what the error says: There is no `devtools` package on the server. You have log in the server and install all needed packages there

Comment: @GGamba thank you. Because I am new to this shiny server. I have installed the package from Rstudio, the directory is not common with shiny server? If it is possible could you give an example of how I should login to the server and install a package?

Comment: @GGamba is it possible to install again packages for shiny server exclusively?

Comment: The output from `which R` in the terminal and `.libPaths()` in RStudio should be the same. If not, you can modify the path in R using `.libPaths(c( .libPaths(), "new path"))`. Check [configuring the server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server) for other options.

Comment: ` $ sudo su - \
        -c "R -e \"install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""` it was worked for me and now my app runs